# when i npm run dev, mongoose connect is not working (not error message) -- express and typescript

Tags: typescript, express, mongoose, package.json

i'm beginner of typescript. 
when i 'npm run dev', it successfully connect to the server (localhost:5000) 
but mongoose.connect is not working. 
i move this db/index.ts to server.ts  
--> it working and terminal shows server connect okay, mongo connet also okay. 
 but that mongoose connect code in db/index.ts is not working...
what's the problem??  can i modify npm scripts??

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --watch '*.ts' --signal SIGTERM --exec ts-node server.ts",
    "build": "tsc -p .",
    "dev": "nodemon --watch \"src/**/*.ts\" --exec \"ts-node\" server.ts",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tsconfig/node16-strictest-esm": "^1.0.3",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.12",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.14",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.11.97",
    "@types/node": "^18.7.19",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.38.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.38.0",
    "eslint": "^8.24.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.8",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsc-watch": "^5.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.8.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.2",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.6.1"
  }
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node16/tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["src/**/*", "bin/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "src/@types"]
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "files": true
  }
}
```

server.ts

```
import 'dotenv/config';
import { app } from './src/app';

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Successfully CONNECT. http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

db/index.ts

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const DB_URL =
  process.env.MONGODB_URL ||
  'MongoDB address is not set.\n check ./db/index.ts \n need .env \n';


mongoose.connect(DB_URL);
const db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('connected', () => console.log('connect success!!' + DB_URL));
db.on('error', (error) =>
  console.error('\n connect fail...\n' + DB_URL + '\n' + error),
);
```

this is my terminal
[image]

Comment: you need to import the `index.ts` file somewhere in order to execute it. It's just not being used / called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you imported db/index.ts into your app.ts? if not then do import

Or/

You've not imported db/index.ts to your server.ts file.

That's why mongodb is not being connected.

what you've to do is "Just import db/index.tx in your server.ts"